# How one actually explores data with linear algebra when matrices are just transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a beginner in ML and I don't quite understand how we can use linear algebra to extract information from our data matrix. For me matrices only have meaning as a transformation between vector spaces but in ML we just construct a matrix from data. Doing a SVD or computing eigenvalues of such a data matrix sounds useless to me but it seems that it isn't useless. Can someone just briefly explain how this works?

Comment: The thing is, by constructing a matrix from data, we have implicitly defined a transformation between two spaces. It turns out there are interesting relationships between properties of that transformation, such as which input vectors it stretches most (the singular vectors), and the directions with the most variance in the data (principle components). I agree it's not immediately obvious that this is true.

Comment: Looking at any [matrix formulation of ordinary least squares regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+least+squares+regression+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10) ought to answer this question immediately.  The point is that these *models* are linear functions of the data (or of "features" computed from the data).